# Cannot return Iterator::Item from function

Tags: rust

I'm writing a function to select a random variant from an enum with the help of the crate strum and its [EnumIter derive macro](https://michael-f-bryan.github.io/mdbook-epub/strum/trait.IntoEnumIterator.html#associatedtype.Iterator):

```
#[derive(EnumIter)]
pub enum Colors {
    Red,
    Blue,
    Purple
}

fn get_random_enum<T: Iterator>(iter: &mut T, rng: &mut Random) -> <T as Iterator>::Item {
    
    let options = iter.collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let count = options.len();
    
    let idx = rng.rand_range(0, (count-1) as u32);
    let item = options[idx as usize];

    return item;
}


fn main() {
    let rng = create_MyRandomNumberGenerator();
    let color = get_random_enum(&mut Colors::iter(), rng);
}
```

This does not compile, as it states that:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<<T as Iterator>::Item>`
  --> stage/main.rs:15:13
   |
15 |     let item = options[idx as usize];
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `<U as Iterator>::Item`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I'm quite new to Rust, but as I understand, `<U as Iterator>::Item` does not implement the Copy trait and that's the reason I cannot just return it.

Checking the generated code by the strum macro, I see that `Item` is just an alias of my Colors enum, but even if I add the `Copy` derive to my enum this still does not work.
I'm quite lost what's the way to implement this in Rust.

Comment: Without looking too depp into it, i would guess that you need to return `item.clone()`
instead of item, since the iterator elements don't neccessarily implement copy. Alternatively,
give the generic iterator type that you use a `Copy` bound for its elements. Just doing it for your concrete struct does not suffice because rust expects the generic function to work for all `T`s.

Comment: the strum EnumIter derive macro offers the `iter()` method on a desired enum. From this you can see in my code I extract the variants defined in my enum with `iter.collect()`. Based on compiler, options is `Vec<<U as Iterator>::Item>`.
Also tried using `item.clone()`, but seems like `clone` method is not available to that type.

Comment: Besides the answers, you don't need to collect in a vector, you can use `size_hint()` to get total variants then use the `nth` to get random variant.  Implementation roughly will be like this [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=127e2c87ae24daf0a185e8db24912eb7)

Comment: Relying to `size_hint`: you can check the implementation of `size_hint` via expanding macros, it returns the count of remaining elements, logically it makes sense since it is a macro it should be able to know the total variants, but ofc always you need to check if there is an implementation for that. ( please search how to expand, if you don't know, I've used `cargo rustc --profile=check -- -Zunpretty=expanded` in nightly to do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in C++, Rust generics are *principled*, meaning that they need to always typecheck for any possible instantiation of their generic parameters. Therefore it does not suffice to implement `Copy` for your concrete struct/enum, but you also need to require it in the generic type bound. The same would even be necessary if we returned a `.clone()`d instance of the `Item`, we would then still need to require the `Clone` trait for any `Item`.

**Solution**: As the compiler hints at, we need the generic function to require the `Item` type of the iterator to implement `Copy`:

```rust
fn get_random_enum<T: Iterator<Item=I>, I: Copy>(iter: &mut T, rng: &mut Random) -> I {
    
    let options = iter.collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let count = options.len();
    
    let idx = rng.rand_range(0, (count-1) as u32);
    let item = options[idx as usize];

    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the desired item from that `Vec` that way you don't have to introduce any more bounds:

```rust
fn get_random_item<T: Iterator>(iter: &mut T, rng: &mut Random) -> <T as Iterator>::Item {
    let mut items = iter.collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let count = items.len();

    let idx = rng.rand_range(0, (count - 1));

    items.swap_remove(idx)
}
```

If your random generator implements `rand::Rng` you can also just use the [`IteratorRandom` extension trait](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.5/rand/seq/trait.IteratorRandom.html) to directly choose on of the items:

```rust
use rand::seq::IteratorRandom;
fn get_random_enum<T: IntoEnumIterator, R: Rng>(rng: &mut R) -> T {
    T::iter().choose_stable(rng).unwrap()
}
```